# Como gerar um valor contendo a "última sexta-feira do mês" usando LocalDate do Java?

Tags: java, data, kotlin

Estou recebendo dados de um arquivo CSV com alguns dados, e um desses dados contém datas aleatórias no seguinte formato: `mm/YYYY`.

Eu tenho um parâmetro `private LocalDate date`. E a partir da data gerada, gostaria de criar uma com a última sexta-feira do mês.

Eu iria gerar ela alterar esse valor dentro do `setDate()`:

```
public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date; // Aqui seria alterado para a ultima sexta-feira do mês.
}
```

Por exemplo: `01/2019`.

A última sexta-feira deste mês foi dia `25/01/2019`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe [`java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html), que possui o método [`lastInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-), passando como parâmetro um [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) correspondente à sexta-feira. Ex:

```
// alguma data em janeiro (1 de janeiro de 2019)
LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1);

// ajustar para a última sexta-feira do mês
LocalDate ultimaSexta = data.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
System.out.println(ultimaSexta); // 2019-01-25
```

Um ponto importante é que as classes da API `java.time` são [imutáveis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html#package.description). Isso quer dizer que métodos que modificam alguma informação (como o método [`with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) acima) sempre retornam **outra** instância, por isso não se deve esquecer de guardar o valor retornado em alguma variável. Se quiser, pode usar inclusive a mesma:

```
// data passa a ser a última sexta-feira do mês
data = data.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
```

Mas repare que [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) exige que se tenha o dia, mês e ano. Como no seu CSV só existe o mês e o ano, não é possível criar um `LocalDate` diretamente (a menos que você artificialmente coloque algum valor para o dia).

---

Uma alternativa é fazer o *parsing* da sua string no formato "mm/yyyy" para um [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), que é uma classe que possui apenas o mês e o ano. E para transformar uma `String` em `YearMonth`, usamos um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
import static java.time.DayOfWeek.FRIDAY;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth;

// String no formato mm/yyyy
String s = "01/2019"; // janeiro de 2019
// definir o formato para mês/ano (MM/yyyy)
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
YearMonth mesAno = YearMonth.parse(s, parser);

// setar um dia arbitrário (1) e depois ajustar para a última sexta-feira do mês
LocalDate ultimaSexta = mesAno.atDay(1).with(lastInMonth(FRIDAY));
System.out.println(ultimaSexta); // 2019-01-25
```

Primeiro eu crio o `DateTimeFormatter` indicando o formato da `String` (no caso, "mês/ano"). Atenção para usar `M` maiúsculo e `y` minúsculo, pois isso faz diferença (veja na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) que `m` minúsculo e `Y` maiúsculo  representam campos diferentes, e se você usá-los erroneamente, [não vai funcionar](https://ideone.com/xXjLHM)).

Depois eu uso o método [`YearMonth.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) para criar o `YearMonth` correspondente. Esta classe só possui o mês e ano, sem qualquer informação sobre o dia. No caso, a instância obtida corresponde à janeiro de 2019.

Em seguida eu seto um dia arbitrário (usando o método [`atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay-int-)), para criar um `LocalDate`. No caso, usei o dia `1`, pois é um valor mais garantido que todos os meses têm (se eu usar o dia `31`, por exemplo, nem todos os meses têm e isso [pode dar erro](https://ideone.com/QIrEh5)).

Tendo o `LocalDate`, eu posso usar `with(lastInMonth(FRIDAY))` (repare que usei `import static` para deixar o código um pouco mais sucinto e legível). O resultado é a última sexta-feira do mês.

---

Pode parecer redundante setar o dia para 1 e só depois ajustar para a última sexta-feira do mês, mas se eu usar `lastInMonth` diretamente no `YearMonth`, dá erro:

```
mesAno.with(lastInMonth(FRIDAY));
```

Este código lança uma exceção:

> java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth

Isso acontece porque `lastInMonth` modifica o dia do mês, mas a classe `YearMonth` não possui nenhuma informação sobre o dia (somente sobre o mês e ano, daí o erro de "*Unsupported field*" - "Campo não suportado"). Por isso é necessário transformá-la em um `LocalDate` antes.

---

#### Alternativa

Se não quiser criar um `YearMonth`, é possível criar um `LocalDate` diretamente. Para isso, basta definir um dia arbitrário (como fizemos acima com o dia 1) e usar um [`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // formato "mês/ano"
    .appendPattern("MM/yyyy")
    // definir o valor default para o dia do mês = 1
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    // cria o DateTimeFormatter
    .toFormatter();
// faz o parse diretamente para LocalDate (o dia é setado para 1)
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse("01/2019", parser);

// ajusta para a última sexta-feira do mês
LocalDate ultimaSexta = data.with(lastInMonth(FRIDAY));
System.out.println(ultimaSexta); // 2019-01-25
```

Primeiro definimos o formato (o mesmo usado no exemplo anterior: mês/ano -> `MM/yyyy`). Depois usamos o método [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-), que serve para definir o valor que um campo terá, caso ele não esteja presente.

Para definir qual campo deve ter o valor *default*, eu usei um [`java.time.temporal.ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html), que é um *enum* que possui várias constantes predefinidas para os campos mais comuns de datas e horas. Como eu quero definir um valor *default* para o **dia do mês**, usei o campo [`DAY_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#DAY_OF_MONTH). Em seguida, eu defino o valor que este campo terá: no caso, é `1`.

Sendo assim, basta usar o método [`LocalDate.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) e obter diretamente um `LocalDate`. O mês e ano terão os valores que estão na `String`, enquanto o dia será `1`. Depois disso, basta ajustar para a última sexta-feira do mês, da mesma maneira que é feito nos exemplos anteriores, com `with(lastInMonth(FRIDAY))`.

Comment: Completo demais! Muito obrigado!